# Entity Framework Core 2.1 failing to translate query properly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an existing database which I am accessing from 2 separate projects, one an ASP.NET MVC 5 project, and one running .NET Core 2.1 using the respective Entity Framework verisons in each.

My problem is that the query that I'm using on the MVC project is being translated incorrectly on the .NET Core project

My 2 models are as follows, a Job which has 0 or more Workorders:

```
public virtual DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }

public class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }

}

public class WorkOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }

    public Job Job { get; set; }

}
```

I've removed all the fields that aren't relevant.

The query that I'm using is pretty simple within the .NET core project:

```
await _context.WorkOrders
.Include(x => x.Job)
.ToListAsync();
```

However this is failing with the following error:

```
  SELECT [x].[WorkOrderId], [x].[JobId], [x.Job].[JobId]
  FROM [WorkOrders] AS [x]
  LEFT JOIN [Jobs] AS [x.Job] ON [x].[JobId] = [x.Job].[JobId]

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'JobId'.
```

If I run this on the database it fails, as the is obviously no [x].[JobId] so EF is getting confused.  What have I done wrong?

**Update**

In the database, my workorders table has a key Job_JobID which is what defines the relationship.  I initially created the tables a while back using EF Code First on the legacy ASP.NET 6 project.  I use migrations on the ASP.NET 6 project, but not on the .NET Core one.

I had the following fluent mapping:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
                        .HasMany(x => x.WorkOrders)
                        .WithOptional(y => y.Job);
```

I have tried adding the virtual keyword for both the relationships but no luck:

```
public virtual ICollection<WorkOrder> WorkOrders { get; set; }

public virtual Job Job { get; set; }
```

Comment: How are the entities related on a database level?

Comment: One job to many work orders. I used ef 6 to generate a code first database initially using the asp.net project. The same query has no issues on the legacy Aspnet project

Comment: Sorry but could you be more precise - maybe give the schema? For that relationship I would expect the WorkOrder table to contain a foreign key linking to the Job table.

Comment: Set your relation properties as virtual in the classes

Comment: Does any of the two versions control the database schema by migrations? What's the name of the FK field in the database?

Comment: I've updated the question with answers to these comments.  Thanks all for your help so far

Comment: @GertArnold I've updated the question, yes, the legacy asp.net project controls the db schema with migrations.  The FK field in the workorders table is Job_JobID

Comment: Thanks @MarcusHöglund, didn't have an effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the foreign key explicitly to the WorkOrder class as it does not match the EFCore convention:

```
public class WorkOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkOrderId { get; set; }

    public int Job_JobID {get;set;} 

    [ForeignKey("Job_JobID")]
    public virtual Job Job { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: That was it thank you, I was unaware of this so appreciate the knowledge!